# Oman visa validity

Tags: visas, oman

I am travelling to Oman from 20th of December to 1st of January. I have applied and received visa `26A - Tourist Visit` (valid for 10 days). "Visa Use By Date" on the visa is 24-12-2018. It says on the visa

> Visa must be used for entry to Oman within 1 month of approval.

Do I correctly understand, that I have to *enter* Oman no later than 24-12-2018? And I can exit Oman after 24-12-2018 as long as I do not exceed the length of my stay stated in the visa (10 days)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As you mentioned, you have a month from approval date to use it.

In this case, they've specified the date by when to use it - the 24th.

Then once activated/used, it's valid for 10 days.

I recommend the Sultan Qaboos Grand Mosque - the scale is very dramatic, and it's a stunning site. Get there early to avoid the midday heat.

Comment: Given it's December, I suspect the midday heat would be welcome :)  (I was there in May, and your advice does make sense for that time of year!)