# Do I need to apply for an Oman visa one month in advance?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, oman

I'm looking at this [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/126201/oman-visa-validity) and I'm trying to understand the procedure for a tourist visa for Oman. While my question is similar it's a bit different.

I will have a 20 hour layover in January (the 14th, 2020) coming from Nepal. The statement made in the above question is:

> Visa must be used for entry to Oman within 1 month of approval.

So, do I need to wait until 1 month (Dec 14th) before I enter Oman to apply as approval can take a few days to a few weeks? I don't see an option during the application process to enter the date of arrival.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the visa usually takes just under 2 weeks to process so you should apply 1 month before entry.

Comment: Okay, so from what I understand, you have to use it within 1 month of date of issue?

Comment: @TravelLikeBeaker yes

Comment: Thank you so much. That's what I thought, but you never know. Appreciate it.

Comment: @TravelLikeBeaker no problem